# Firestore listeners

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I have multiple tables from which I get data on app start. 
I use get() and getting multiple tables is pretty slow so I end up with terribly slow app start.
Around 5 seconds (unbelievable).

So my idea is to fetch all data only once, and later just attach listeners for Firestore changes. I tried to use addSnapshotListener but it gets data first, and again I spend 5s to get all data which is not necessary.

Is there a way just to attach listener without getting data?

Generally, I need some smart approach for this. It is not custom server to watch for updates and sync periodically.

Any ideas?

Queries are quite simple and this is one example:

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("someData").get().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (final QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                //extract data
            }
        } else {
            Log.w(TAG, "Error getting documents.", task.getException());
        }
    });
```

Table can have up to 10 fields, not more. 
I have 8 tables, so maximum is 80 fields.
Also, I don't have much data on Firestore, around 200 results are received in onSnapshotListener. 
How long it is gonna be after a year of usage? Very long.

Network is good, 100MB and load is smallest possible.

Comment: How much later is "later" when you attached listeners?  The documents should come from cache if they are already fully fetched.  It might be nice if you show some code and help us understand the timeline of events here.

Comment: Thanks for reply.
Splash screen -> load 8 tables (takes 5s), save in local database (SQLite)
Main screen -> data present, load it from database - fast, no network queries

I want to attach listeners in Main screen, and never again query all tables from server so start will be fast. I have all data in local db and listeners will notify me about changes in Firestore. I wonder if this is even possible.

Comment: I don't use Firestore caching.. Maybe I should?

Comment: It's on by default.  That shoudn't be changed unless you have a really good reason to disable. it.

Comment: I wanted to say that I rely on local database, not on Firestore cache.
On start, it triggers around 200 changes in all tables, and takes up to 8 seconds for that. That is so so so slow.

Comment: If you're going to implement your own local cache, you've got a lot of work ahead of you to be as robust and flexible as the Firestore's own cache.

Comment: @DougStevenson Any idea why getting data is so slow?

Comment: No.  Without seeing the code, the query, the size of the result set, and the quality of the network connection, it's not really possible to say anything about the observed speed.

Comment: @DougStevenson Code is simplest possible and tables are regular, nothing fancy... I attached one example. Thanks for help

Comment: Well, you are getting the entire collection.  Anything you can do to pare down the result set will improve speed.  You still haven't said anything about the quality of the network, which could be as fast as local WIFI, or a slow as 2G.

Comment: It's wifi in house, 100mb is the speed. I would get only new entries, but not sure how to achieve that with Firestore. Keep a date in table, and compare, something like that.